# Why android data binding library is not working as expected?

Tags: android, android-activity, data-binding, android-databinding

I am new to concept of Android Data Binding, i have read it from [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/say-goodbye-to-findviewbyid-with-data-binding-library/en) blog and it is working properly with simple examples they had provided , I have taken a blank activity so there will be two files `activity_main.xml` and `content_main.xml` 
 
This is `activity_main.xml` code

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_sync_noanim" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </layout>
```

As suggested i have taken parent as layout, and from java side i am accessing it as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);


         setSupportActionBar(activityMainBinding.toolbar);
        //Floating Action Button
         activityMainBinding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

This is ok and i can access all my views under `activity_main.xml` but for accessing contents inside `content_main.xml` i have done this in `MainActivity.java`

```
ContentMainBinding contentMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.content_main,clActivityMain,true);
 contentMainBinding.tvHello.setText("yippee"); <br/>
```

Problem is that it can not change the default text value provided from xml side in `content_main.xml` EX : `<android:Text = "Hello World!">` **and shows me both values(Provided in xml layout + Which i have set from java side)**  I have already read it in **Developer Documentation** but its so much different then this blog i have read. Is there any proper way for this? As developer documentation or mentioned as in [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/say-goodbye-to-findviewbyid-with-data-binding-library/en) Blog ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might check out:

https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-that-include-thing-1c8791dd6038#.p7nhkxhdt

You don't need to inflate that included layout, but you should give the include an ID if you want to access the included layout's binding:

```
<include android:id="@+id/contentMain" layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Now, you can access the content like this:

```
binding.contentMain.tvHello.setText("yippee");
```

Comment: Ok got it but my problem is when I set value of that textview from my activity then it shows both values which was there already set from XML and which I have set from java . Will this solution solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah its perfectly fine @GeorgeMount